# Fedora linux VNC scripting help

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, fedora

I'm trying to make a bash script for a school project which i am using a Fedora system which requires me to launch VNC viewer(TigerVNC), automate any password entry so that no passwords will have to be entered when the script is executed.

So far i've made a script called vnc.sh with the command touch vnc.sh.
In the script i have entered these lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
#launch vnc
vncviewer -via student@192.168.59.1 192.168.59.1:4
```

The command prompt will then ask for the student@192.168.59.1 password and then after entering the password a new window will pop up asking for the VNC authentication password before it will connect. I would like to know if there is a way to make the script input the passwords automatically and connect to the remote desktop without having to enter the passwords and hitting enter?

Comment: It is possible to script actions via X11 (the base system for GUI on Linux/Unix) e.g. with xdotool (https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xdotool/) but it is FAR from easy. I would suggest you exhaust any and all other options before trying this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with your specific VNC client, `vncviewer`, but I read `man vncviewer` (that `man` program is "manual pages". You can find manuals for many commands that way!), and that tells me there's an option:

```
-passwdInput true, false
    Force standard vnc dialog to getting password and reads password from stdin. Default is false(shows dialog window)
```

So, you'd add `-passwdInput true` to your `vncviewer` command line, and feed in the password from standard input. Like so:

```bash
echo my_secret_passwort | vncviewer -passwdInput true -via student@192.168.59.1 192.168.59.1:4
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that we were told to install TigerVNC Viewer before using the command vncviewer -via student@192.168.59.1 192.168.59.1:4. I have also tried the code above doesn't seem to work but when i enter the wrong parameters it seems like the manual comes up for Tiger VNC and it does have =passwd option (Alias for PasswordFile) and a -PasswordFile option (Pasword file for VNC authentication (default =)) so i'm guessing i'm supposed to make a password file and feed the file location to that option?

Comment: Don't know tigerVNC, either, but what does its documentation say?

Comment: So after a bit more reading i was able to figure it out, so there's a password file for the VNC password on the server server side (the server is the computer i'm trying to connect to.) So i copied the password file, moved it to my client machine and used the command like this [vncviewer -passwd "location of password file" -via student@192.168.59.1 192.168.59.1:4]. This will bypass the vncpassword. I have also been told that and easier way to bypass the vnc user password is to generate a public and private SSH key. So ill have to work on that. Thanks to your answer it set me on the right path.